# Create a Shell Service in Ubuntu

Tags: linux, unix, services, shell-script

I want to create a service, which receives input from a shell script and returns outputs.

where should I start, and what to do ? Please give me step by step instruction or reference to one.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you mean by "a service". Do you mean something that can be invoked and run in the background? If so, your needs might be satisfied by a Bash script that polls a file for input, takes input when it is found in the file (presumably it would be [piped in](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html) by the shell script that generates the input), and then outputs via whatever mechanism you choose. You could wrap the polling in an infinite loop with a `sleep` statement, and background the script to run continuously via [nohup](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nohup) ([manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/1/nohup)). That said, I'm not sure that's robust enough for your purposes, mostly because I'm not truly sure what you're asking. So let's take a few steps back:

There are many ways to write daemons/services in Unix, and your question should be a little more specific if you want step-by-step instructions. Some good places to start might be: what language do you want to write this in? What kinds of inputs will this service be taking? What will it be outputting, in what form, and to where/for whom/what recipient? At a higher level: do you really need a service for this, or is what you're after some sort of persistently-caching data processor, which could run as a standalone executable? The latter is often the better choice, especially when starting from scratch, as you can outsource a lot of rapid-sequential/simultaneous invocation problems to the back-end persistence provider (in my imagining, something like [sqlite](http://www.sqlite.org/)).

If you'd like to write it in Bash (which might not be the best option), I'd suggest starting [here](http://blog.n01se.net/blog-n01se-net-p-145.html). Be sure you fully understand the basics of UNIX process forking and monitoring, otherwise writing daemons that perform arbitrary functions can be a significantly-sized "foot gun".

Bash, as I said before, isn't necessarily the best choice here. Perl contains a pretty robust built-in facility for doing this, in the form of Proc::Daemon. [This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/766397/how-can-i-run-a-perl-script-as-a-system-daemon-in-linux) should get you pointed in the right direction if you choose Perl.

Python, also, has this ability. The canonical example of a Python daemon, complete with the double-fork magic, and a brief explanation, can be found [here](http://www.jejik.com/articles/2007/02/a_simple_unix_linux_daemon_in_python/).

C/C++ is also a common language for daemon-writing, and there are plenty of guides. I like [this one](http://narcissisticme.com/2011/01/31/lets-write-a-linux-daemon-part-i/), but my experience in that area is more limited than the other languages above.

All of the above aside, this question probably belongs on [Stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com).

Comment: I didn't migrate the question, because as your answer shows, its not really well defined what the OP is really trying. So either he goes to SO with a (new) more specific or the solution is some scripted solution which would be fine for SU. If you still disagree, feel free to flag again

Answer (score 0):

If you want to write a daemon and you are a C programmer, grab yourself a copy of *The Linux Programming Interface: A Linux and UNIX System Programming Handbook*; it has a whole chapter on it and is so valuable.